# Retrieving images once saved to a server

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I have code written that uploads an image to the server, but I am not sure how to retrieve the images after I upload them. I tried using an NSURL request, but the did receiveData delegate method is never called. Below I've included all relevant code related to uploading the picture, and then my attempt at pulling the data using an NSURL request. Is there anything conceptually that I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[self.signupController uploadProfilePicture:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image) completion:^(NSError *error){
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[SyncController sharedInstance] sync];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsSegue" sender:self];
    }];
}];
}
```

And the uploadProfilePicture method:

```
- (void)uploadProfilePicture:(NSData *)imageData completion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {
BRUser *user = [BRSession userWithContext:[[BRCoreDataManager sharedManager] mainContext]];
[self.apiClient uploadProfilePicture:imageData forUser:user parameters:nil completion:[self uploadProfilePictureHandlerWithCompletion:completion]];
}
```

And then, also, here is the upload profile picture method in the API client:

```
- (void)uploadProfilePicture:(NSData *)imageData forUser:(BRUser *)user parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters completion:(BRAPIClientCompletionBlock)completion {
NSError *error;
NSURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer multiformRequestForAPIAction:BRAPIActionCreate nestedResource:@"image" parent:user data:imageData parameters:parameters error:&error];
if (error) {
    completion(nil, error);
}
NSURLSessionDataTaskCompletionBlock dataTaskCompletion = [self requestHandlerWithHTTPStatusErrors:@{ @400 : @(BRAPIUnauthorized) }  completion:completion];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.authURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:dataTaskCompletion];
[task resume];
}
```

and the multiform method called in the previous method:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)multiformRequestForAPIAction:(BRAPIAction)action nestedResource:(id)resource parent:(id)parent data:(NSData *)data parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
NSParameterAssert(action);
NSParameterAssert(resource);
NSParameterAssert(parent);
NSParameterAssert(data);

NSString *method = [BRAPIRequestSerializer HTTPMethodForAPIAction:action];
NSURL *url = [self.apiURL nestedURLForResource:resource parent:parent];
NSLog(@"URL: %@",[url absoluteStringWithTrailingSlash]);

return [self.serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:method
                                             URLString:[url absoluteStringWithTrailingSlash]
                                            parameters:parameters
                             constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                 [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"image" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
                             }
                                                 error:error];
}
```

And my failed attempt at retrieving the data via the url it's stored at:

```
-(void) downloadImageFromURL :(NSString *)imageUrlString{
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

// Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
NSData * receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (!theConnection) {
    // Release the receivedData object.
    receivedData = nil;

    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    NSLog(@"connection falied");
} else {
    NSLog(@"connection succesful");
};
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    NSLog(@"data: %@",data);
}
```

I also made sure to include the NSURLConnectionDelegate. The didRecieveData method is never called.

Feel free to let me know if there's more code you need to see!

Comment: Did you implement connection:didFailWithError:?  That will probably get invoked, and the error will probably provide a clue about what's gone wrong.